# Scriptable testing/debugging HTTP/HTTPS cookies and redirects

Tags: http, testing, https, cookies, security

I need to setup some automated testing of HTTP requests, to check cookies are doing the right thing, with (manual) debugging when there is a problem.

So far I've been muddling along with Firebug, but it's quite a bit of effort using that, and I would prefer some form of scriptable tool, both to make it easier for me and to allow an automated regression test.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe httpUnit is suitable for your needs...
http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hmmm, I was looking more for a scriptable application, rather than a programming framework. I'll investigate it further, but I suspect it may be a lot of effort to create what I want with HttpUnit.